# How to connect with linux server using SSH connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, asp.net-mvc-4, ssh

I am new to SSH connection & trying to connect using SSH connection but getting exception:

```
Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Renci.SshNet.Common.SshException.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'
```

Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.

Please somebody help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Mark `GetObjectData` with `SecurityCriticalAttribute`, because it's applied to `Exception.GetObjectData`. An overridden member should have the same security accessibility (Critical, Safe Critical or Transparent).

[More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233103%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[image]

Comment: Try adding `[SecurityCritical]` before your method declaration

Comment: alexx..please help me

Comment: I have no idea bout renci.sshnet.dll, But what Alexander told you is to put [SecurityCritical] right above 'Private void DoConnect()'

Comment: Is there any other library for ssh connection except renci

Comment: Try [Grandos](http://granados.sourceforge.net/) , or [sshnet](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/)